# why use references for mutable variables in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, copy, auto

I'm new to c++. I came across some code and got confused

```cpp
vector<int> vec{3,1,4,1,5};
vector<int> &vecRef = vec;
auto vecCopy = vecRef; // makes copy of vec
auto &vecRef2 = vecRef; // reference
```

I read about the usage of reference types in c++ and I understand why it's useful for immutable types. But for mutable types like vectors, what's the difference between vector vecCopy = vec and vector& vecRef = rec? Aren't they both alias to vec?

Comment: Why do you think `vector vecCopy = vec;` makes an alias? Your own example specifically says you expect copies, not aliasing.

Comment: As you said in your code `vecCopy` is a copy.  Do you want to copy the data, or just refer to it with a different name?

Comment: I think OP may be seeing `vec` as "a handle to a vector", in which case I can understand the confusion. Saying `vecCopy` could seem like copying the handle from that perspective. It's important to understand that objects in C++ like `vec` are *the* object, not a handle to the object. To copy it means to create a new object with a copy of the value the original has at the time the copy is made. It is not creating a new handle to the same object. That is the distinction between object and reference to an object. It seems likely OP comes from a Java background or similar.

Comment: The `mutable` keyword has a specific meaning in C++; you probably didn't encounter it yet in your book but it makes the title confusing.

Comment: To expand on @MSalters's comment, the preferred term is non-const instead of mutable, to distinguish with the keyword called `mutable`.

Comment: OP: I think [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics) might answer all of your questions regarding values and references in C++.

Comment: I see. I came from python and assumed that ```vector vecCopy = vec;``` creates an alias

Comment: @Kathryn C++ is a bit different in that by default it has value semantics, variables are objects, not references to objects.

Answer (score 3):

#### Difference between references and values.

One of the features of C++ is that it distinguishes between references and values. A lot of other languages don't do this. Let's say you have a vector:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
```

Creating a deep copy of this vector is really simple:

```
auto copy_of_v1 = v1;
```

We can prove it by changing `copy_of_v1`:

```
std::cout << (v1 == copy_of_v1) << '\n'; // Prints 1, for true

copy_of_v1[1] = 20; // copy_of_v1 == {1, 20, 3} now

std::cout << (v1 == copy_of_v1) << '\n'; // Prints 0, for false
```

#### Use cases for references.

References have three big use cases:
- Avoiding a copy by storing/using a reference
- Getting additional information out of a function (by passing it a reference, and letting it modify the reference)
- Writing data structures / container classes

We've seen the first case already, so let's look at the other two.

**Using references to write functions that modify their input.** Let's say you wanted to add the ability to append elements to vectors using `+=`. An operator is a function, so if it's going to modify the vector, it needs to have a reference to it:

```
// We take a reference to the vector, and return the same reference
template<class T>
std::vector<T>& operator +=(std::vector<T>& vect, T const& thing) {
    vect.push_back(thing); 
    return vect;
}
```

This allows us to append elements to the vector just like it was a string:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;

    ((a += 1) += 2) += 3; // Appends 1, then 2, then 3

    for(int i : a) {
        std::cout << i << '\n'; 
    }
}
```

*If we didn't take the vector by reference, the function wouldn't be able to change it.* This means that we wouldn't be able to append anything.

**Using references to write containers.**

References make it easy to write mutable containers in C++. When we want to provide access to something in the container, we just return a reference to it. This provides direct access to elements, even primitives.

```
template<class T>
class MyArray {
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> array;
    size_t count; 
   public:
    T* data() {
       return array.get();
    }
    T const* data() {
       return array.get();
    }
    MyArray() = default;         // Default constructor
    MyArray(size_t count)        // Constructs array with given size
      : array(new T[count])
      , count(count) {}
    MyArray(MyArray const& m)    // Copy constructor
      : MyArray(count) {
        std::copy_n(m.data(), count, data();
    }
    MyArray(MyArray&&) = default;// Move constructor

    // By returning a reference, we can access elements directly 
    T& operator[](size_t index) {
       return array[index]; 
    }
};
```

Now, when using `MyArray`, we can directly change and modify elements, even if they're primitives:

```
MyArray<int> m(10); // Create with 10 elements

m[0] = 1;           // Modify elements directly

m[0]++;             // Use things like ++ directly
```

Answer (score 2):

> But for mutable types like vectors, what's the difference between
>   vector vecCopy = vec and vector& vecRef = rec? Aren't they both alias
>   to vec?

No. One is a copy of the entire vector. The other is a reference to the same.

Your example code is contrived. I can't think of any reasons why you would do this:

```
vector<int> vec{3,1,4,1,5};
vector<int> &vecRef = vec;
```

You pass variables by reference **all the time**. But I can't imagine a reason why I'd make a reference to a local variable like this, other than to illustrate an example of references as opposed to copies.

So: vecCopy is a whole DIFFERENT vector with its own contents. At the end of your code, it's identical in contents to vec, but after that, you can add to one or the other and they begin to diverge. vecRef is a reference to the exact same data. If you think of them as (under the hood) pointers, they point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Using references in c++ is the same as just using the name of the object itself. Therefore, you might consider a reference an alias.

```
vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};

vector<int>& vecRef = vec;

cout << vec.size()    << '\n'; // Prints '3'
cout << vecRef.size() << '\n'; // Also prints '3'
```

It's worth noting that nobody really uses references to simply have another name for an existing object. 
They are primarily used instead of pointers to pass objects without copying them.

Comment: Now that you've pointed it out, I can see why it would cause confusion. I've edited the answer.

Comment: "nobody really uses references to simply have another name for an existing object" – I do that pretty often. It's very useful when you need a better name for something nested in something else. For instance, `Foo& o = things[i].bar.baz; o.do_something(); o.do_somethingelse(); do_anotherthing(o); o = something();`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ uses value semantics by default. Objects are values unless you specifically declare them to be references. So:

```
auto vecCopy = vecRef;
```

will create a value object called `vecCopy` which will contain a deep copy of `vec` since `vecRef` is an alias for `vec`. In Python, this would roughly translate to:

```
import copy

vec = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
vecCopy = copy.deepcopy(vec)
```

Note that it only "roughly" translates to that. How the copy is performed depends on the type of the object. For built-in types (like `int` and `char` for example,) it's a straightforward copy of the data they contain. For class types, it invokes either the copy constructor, or the copy assignment operator (in your example code, it's the copy constructor.) So it's up to these special member functions to actually perform the copy. The default copy constructor and assignment operators will copy each class member, which in turn might invoke that member's copy ctor or assignment operator if it has one, etc, etc, until everything has been copied.

Value semantics in C++ allow for certain code generation optimizations by the compiler that would be difficult to perform when using reference semantics. Obviously if you copy large objects around, the performance benefit of values will get nullified by the performance cost of copying data. In these cases, you would use references. And obviously you need to use references if you need to modify the passed object rather than a copy of it.

In general, value semantics are preferred unless there is a reason to use a reference. For example, a function should take parameters by value, unless the passed argument needs to be modified, or it's too big.

Also, using references can increase the risk of running into undefined behavior (pointers incur the same risks.) You can have dangling references for example (a reference that refers to a destroyed object, for example.) But you can't have dangling values.

References can also decrease your ability to reason about what is going on in the program because objects can get modified through references by non-local code.

In any event, it's a rather big subject. Things start to become more clear as you use the language and gain more experience with it. If there's a *very* general rule of thumb to take away from all this: use values unless there's a reason not to (mostly object size, requiring mutability of a passed function argument, or with runtime polymorphic classes since those *require* to be accessed through a reference or pointer when that access needs to be polymorphic.)

You can also find beginner articles and talks about the subject. Here's one to get you started:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkyD1iv3ATU